# How to iterate heapq without losing data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heapq

In Python 3 I'm using heapq like so:

```
import heapq

heap = [3]
heapq.heapify(heap)
heapq.heappush(heap, 5)
# Push more values...

# I can iterate heap like so, but by the end it will be empty:
while (heap):
    curr = heapq.heappop(heap)
    # Do whatever with curr
```

**Is there a way to iterate heapq such that I get the values in sorted order without mutating heapq/losing data?**

**If not, how can I efficiently imitate the desired behavior?**

The solution I came up with is to create a temporary heap, push to it as I pop from the original heap, and once I'm done iterating set the original heap equal to the temporary heap.

Of course this is not very efficient, and changes the object which the original heap referenced.

```
temp = []
heapq.heapify(temp)

while(heap):
    curr = heapq.heappop(heap)
    heapq.heappush(temp, curr)
    # Do whatever with curr
heap = temp
```

Comment: Heaps aren't meant to be iterated over.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Agree with @chepner, heaps are meant to be iterated over, if iteration is an requirement, you should consider use Binary Search Tree.

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is all values on the heap, in sorted order, then *just sort the heap*. Using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) gives you the sequence in sorted order, without altering the heap list itself:

```
sorted(heap)
```

or, since a list in sorted order is also a valid heap, sort the heap in place:

```
heap.sort()
```

The sort algorithm used, [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), benefits from the partial ordering already inherent in a heap structure, and definitely going to be more efficient than popping values off the heap one by one then constructing a new heap.

The `heap` value itself is nothing special, by the way, it's *just a list*. Note also that a heap is a data structure aimed at giving you access to the lowest (or highest) value efficiently, not to be iterated over in full. It's essentially a binary tree, with each level of the tree laid out into a list, in depth order.

Comment: The partial ordering doesn't seem to help Timsort much. I tried sorting a million random numbers and sorting the same numbers after heapifying, and the latter was only about 5% faster.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: 5% is still a win!

Comment: Sure, that's why I said it doesn't help "much" :-). I can't even tell which part of Timsort is responsible for that speedup. It's not like there are long already sorted runs. Longest occurring runs were 10 elements long, well below minrun (=32) and barely longer than the longest occurring runs in the random order, which were 9 elements long. And average run length was only 2.55 elements (2.50 for random order).

Comment: @HeapOverflow: I didn't check this in any detail, but I suspect it's the galloping mode when merging that benefits from the power-of-two distances between tree depths.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the underlying list, i.e. `temp = copy(heap)` and iterate over it as you did, that is via

```
while(temp):
    curr = heapq.heappop(temp)
```

While the copy is `O(N)`, the traversal will be `O(N log N)`. So there remains a problem on how to traverse a `heapq` in `O(N)`.